# ICollectionView ui is not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collections, entity

I have ObserveCollection (entity) associated with ICollectionView
Everything works fine until I try to delete the entry. After clicking on the 'delete' button, the interface is not updated.
If i set ObserveCollection everything works fine

```
private ICollectionView _taskview;
public ICollectionView TasksView 
{
    get { return _taskview; }
    set
    {
        _taskview = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TaskView");
    }
}
public ICommand DeleteTask
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            _context.Task.Attach(SelectTask);
            _context.Task.Remove(SelectTask);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            Tasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskModel>(_context.Task);
            TasksView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Tasks);
        });
    }
}

public HomeViewModel(Window window)
{
    this.window = window;
    Tasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskModel>(_context.Task);
    TasksView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Tasks);
}


  <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
                    SelectionMode="Extended"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding TasksView}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectTask}">
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: `ObservableCollection` implements has the event `CollectionChanged` which  signals for a 'repaint'. Stick to using it otherwise call `OnPropertyChanged` after delete action.

Comment: I tried to do this too, but the number of records in the interface still doesn't change after deleting

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new collection after each deletion. This will have negative impact on the performance. This is the reason why you use an `ObservableCollection`. This way the binding target e.g., a `ListBox` is able to update the changed items only, instead of recreating/rendering the complete view.

In this this context it also doesn't make sense to expose the data source as `ICollectionsView`. Rather bind to the `ObservableCollection` directly.

When the source collection of an `ICollectionsView` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` like `ObservableCollection<T>` does, then the `ICollectionView` will automatically update when the source changes.
In this case manipulating the `INotifyCollectionChanged` collection is sufficient.

When the source collection of an `ICollectionsView` *does not* implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` like `List<T>`, then the `ICollectionView` *will not* automatically update when the source changes.
In this case you must explicitely call `ICollectionView.Refresh` to force the `ICollectionView` to update.

Please note that you should *never* reference any view components in your view model - no exceptions. This eliminates all benefits of MVVM. And it is *never* necessary, for sure. If your view model requires a reference to a view component that you are designing your code or classes wrong.
To follow this basic and fundamental MVVM design rule you *must* remove the reference to `Window` from your `HomeViewModel`.
You can trigger view behavior by exposing a property on the view model which is the input for a data trigger in the view. [Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern), [The Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm).

### First Solution (Recommended)

You should bind to the `Tasks` collection directly.
The moment you need to manipulate the collection's view e.g., to apply a filter retrieve the view using `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Tasks)`. But don't bind to it.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" />

public HomeViewModel()
{
  Tasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskModel>(_context.Task);
  Tasks.CollectionChanged += OnTasksChanged;
}

private void OnTasksChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Action)
  {
    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
    {
      foreach (TaskModel task in e.NewItems)
      {
        _context.Task.Add(task);
        _context.SaveChanges();
      }
      break;
    }
    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
    {
      foreach (TaskModel task in e.OldItems)
      {
        _context.Task.Attach(task);
        _context.Task.Remove(task);
        _context.SaveChanges();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Then simply manipulate the 'Tasks' collection
public ICommand DeleteTaskCommand => new DelegateCommand(() => Tasks.Remove(SelectTask));
```

### Second Solution

If you want to bind to the `ICollectionView`, you don't need the additional `ObservableCollection` anymore (except you want to maintain two collections and a `ICollectionView` on every add/move/remove/reset operation). To update the collection's view call `ICollectionView.Refresh`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TasksView}" />

public HomeViewModel()
{
  TasksView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_context.Task);
}


// Then simply refresh the 'TasksView': 
public ICommand DeleteTask => DelegateCommand(
  () =>
  {
    _context.Task.Attach(SelectTask);
    _context.Task.Remove(SelectTask);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    // Update the view
    TasksView.Refresh();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Refresh() on View property of CollectionViewSource to get it refreshed.

Comment: don't create a new instance of taskview in the delegate, update the context and after that call refresh.

Comment: It's funny that with observecollection everything works as it should, at the same time I look at icollectionview in the debugger and its data is updated, then onproperty works, HOWEVER, the UI still doesn't change for some reason, it's very strange

Comment: can you share your repository?

Comment: sorry if the format is inconvenient, here is the zip link:
http://fayloobmennik.cloud/7401165
(did not upload terrible things to github)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on:

```
public ICollectionView TasksView 
{
    get { return _taskview; }
    set
    {
        _taskview = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TaskView");
    }
}
```

At **OnPropertyChanged("TaskView");** it should be `OnPropertyChanged("TasksView");`